# Slurping JSON collections in Groovy

Tags: json, groovy, deserialization

I have a String of JSON that looks like this:

```
String json = """
    {       
        "content":{
            "response":{
                "body": [
                    {
                        "firstName":"Jim",
                        "lastName":"Smith"
                    },
                    {
                        "firstName":"Joe",
                        "lastName":"Smith"
                    },
                    {
                        "firstName":"Jane",
                        "lastName":"Smith"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
"""
```

I have a POJO that looks like this:

```
class Person {
    String firstName
    String surname
}
```

I can change neither the JSON string I am given (it's actually JSON coming back from a web service) nor the POJO (owned/maintained by a different team).

**I would like to turn this JSON into a `List<Person>`.**

My attempt via `JsonSlurper` is failing:

```
JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()
List<Person> people = []
// The problem is I don't know how many people there will be so
// not sure how to index the slurper.
```

I *think* the best approach is to iterate through the `slurper` and turn each person JSON object into a `Person` instance, and then add that person to the list of `people`. But I'm not that familiar with `JsonSlurper`'s API or what the best approach even is.

Comment: note, that the JSON there is invalid.  you might need to run the LAX-mode.

Comment: Apologies @cfrick (+1) - copy/paste error; please see my revision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the list by `collect()`ing the entries:

```
List<Person> l = slurper.content.response.body.collect{ new Person(firstName: it.firstName, surname: it.lastName) }
```

e.g.:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.transform.ToString

String json = """
    {       
        "content":{
            "response":{
                "body": [
                    {
                        "firstName":"Jim",
                        "lastName":"Smith",
                    },
                    {
                        "firstName":"Joe",
                        "lastName":"Smith",
                    },
                    {
                        "firstName":"Jane",
                        "lastName":"Smith",
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
"""

@ToString
class Person {
    String firstName
    String surname
}

def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
List<Person> l = slurped.content.response.body.collect {new Person(firstName: it.firstName, surname: it.lastName) }
assert l.size() == 3
```

Comment: the code lacks `slurped`.  must be either a LAX slurper (not tested) or the JSON must be fixed (tested).

Comment: I've fixed JSON and added `slurped`.

Answer (score 0):

well, no need to explicitly construct Person object:

(groovy-shell)

```
@ToString
class Person {
    String firstName
    String lastName
}

slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
l = slurped.content.response.body.collect {it as Person}
```

Just need to be sure that `Person` type represents json completely (e.g. field names are equal)
This is a tricky part, because Groovy parser is kinda cranky. I mean, if you don't rename  `surname` to `lastName`, the json list will be parsed, but all field of all three Person instances will remain `null`

More magic with objects, if you don't like dynamically typed maps:

```
@ToString
class Some {
    Content content
}

@ToString
class Content {
    Response response
}

@ToString
class Response {
    Person[] body
}

cnt = slurped as Some
println cnt.dump()
```

will print

```
<Some@62ddbd7e content=Content(Response([Person(Jim, Smith), Person(Joe, Smith), Person(Jane, Smith)]))>
```